# React native code behind class

Tags: react-native

Sorry I am new to this. Just wondering if there is a way to add a code behind file. basically I am trying to add a file where I can write up all my SQL code to execute update, insert data etc and access it from different containers / screens. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export functions in js files then import them in any other component files to use them.

e.g. importing a function from util folder

in `src/util/myFunc.js` :

```
function myFunc(param) {
// do something
}
export default myFunc;
```

in `src/views/mainScreen.js` :

```
import myFunc from './util/myFunc'
```

Comment: I realised how silly my question was once I woke up this morning. I am already doing it for Sagas. anyway thanks. needed sleep i think